# jQuery Ajax plugin for ColdFusion developers

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, coldfusion

I've written a plugin to supply all my popular ColdFusion defaults such as:

- returnFormat=json
- queryFormat=column
- type='post'
- dataType='json'
- .fail()
- .done() (but with a caught error)

It is working, but I don't know why I have to use

```
myXHR = $.fn.myAjax()
```

instead of

```
myXHR = $.myAjax()
```

Here's the code:

```
!function($) {
    $.extend(
        $.fn, {
            myAjax: function(myURL, settings) {
                var local = {};
                $('#msg').empty().removeClass('alert alert-info');
                local.settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.ajaxDefaults, settings);
                local.myURL = myURL + '?returnFormat=json&queryFormat=column'
                local.result = $.ajax(local.myURL,local.settings)
                local.result.done(function(result) {
                    if (result.MSG) {
                        $('#msg').html(result.MSG).addClass('alert alert-info');
                    }
                });
                local.result.fail(function(A,B,C) {
                    $('#msg').html(C).addClass('alert alert-info');
                });
                return local.result;
            },
            ajaxDefaults:{
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                async:false
                // todo: context = this
            }
        }
    )

    $('input[type=checkbox]').bind('change', function(myEvent, ui) {
        var settings = {};
        settings.data = {};
        settings.data.PersonID = $(this).val();
        settings.context = this;

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            settings.data.method = 'check';

            myXHR = $.fn.myAjax('Evnt.cfc',settings);
            myXHR.done(function(result) {
                if (!result.MSG) {
                    log(result.QRY.DATA);
                }
            });
        } else {
            settings.data.method = 'uncheck';
            myXHR = $.fn.myAjax('Evnt.cfc',settings);
            myXHR.done(function(result) {
                if (!result.MSG) {
                    log(result.QRY.DATA);
                }
            });
        }
    });


}(jQuery);
```

Comment: The 'alert alert-info' classes are for the Blueprint css framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've essentially set up your plugin like this:

```
( function($) {
  $.fn.doSomething = function() {
    // stuff
  };
}(jQuery));
```

...and therefore have a plugin that operates on jQuery objects. So this would work:

```
$('#something').doSomething();
```

But you're calling it like this:

```
$.doSomething(); // doesn't work
```

Since you apparently want your function to stand alone within the jQuery namespace, you'd set it up like this:

```
$.doSomething = function(){
  // stuff
};
```

So in the case of your code, try adding this at the bottom, right above the end of your function:

```
$.myAjax = $.fn.myAjax;
```

As a side note, it's not considered good practice to add more than one namespace for your plugin (`ajaxDefaults` from your example). It's worth a quick read through the jQuery [Plugin Authoring page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) for some good tips.

Comment: Thank you Ken!  That page is not a quick read.  But I will stare at it some more.

Comment: @Pedro, there are also various plugin generator frameworks floating around to ease the process. But the short answer is: add that one line to the bottom of your plugin.